# How does one immediately replay cards returned to hand?

Tags: hearthstone

Watching some of the pros play Hearthstone, I've noticed that they are able to immediately play a card returned to their hand, somehow issuing the instruction before the card rematerializes in their hand.

For example, the rope is burning and the pro has just calculated lethal. The pro does a flurry of activity which includes playing a [Leeroy Jenkins](http://www.hearthpwn.com/cards/674-leeroy-jenkins), attacking with Leeroy Jenkins, using [Shadowstep](http://www.hearthpwn.com/cards/550-shadowstep) to return said Leeroy, playing Leeroy again, and attacking with the [Leeroy Jenkins](http://www.hearthpwn.com/cards/674-leeroy-jenkins) a second time. The rope burns out during the [Shadowstep](http://www.hearthpwn.com/cards/550-shadowstep) animation.

However, this is a pro, and after the rope burns out, the [Leeroy Jenkins](http://www.hearthpwn.com/cards/674-leeroy-jenkins) which is returning to hand, immediately comes back into play *and* attacks.

As an amateur, I have to wait until the minion becomes a card again and returns to my hand before I can play it the second time. I also have to wait until the card is in play to attack.

How do these pros do it?

[This video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sXEWsz3h1L8&t=15m40s), starting at 15:40 is a good example of a pro seemingly magically playing Leeroy Jenkins out of his hand without moving his mouse.

Comment: Are you watching streams/recordings of the pros playing from their point of view? If so, can you link an example of this?

Comment: @Studoku Found a video for you and linked to it in the question.

Comment: Is it possible to play cards via keyboard? Like pressing "1" to play card on left side. I´m not sure have not tested it.

Comment: They might be using some external programs to automate actions, like playing the Xth card in my hand, attack with the Xth minions on the board.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau It is almost certainly not an external program. I've seen this on televised tournaments in which the players are not using their own computers.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Trump is making use of the click-to-select then click-to-place mechanism in Hearthstone instead of the more usual drag process used.

When he plays Shadowstep, the card he targets to be returned will light up green as it's returned to your hand (assuming you have enough mana to play it) this means it's selectable, as your cursor is over the card (from selecting the Shadowstep target) it's easy to click again and "select" Leeroy.

Trump then clicks on the board just to the right of Leeroy as the card is being returned to the hand to issue the "place" command.

These two "events" (the Shadowstep click on Leeroy and the click on the board) are detected and queued up to be played in turn just the same as when you get ahead of the animations whilst dragging a lot of cards quickly around.

Comment: Thank you! This is awesome. Just to add some icing now that I know how: To replay a minion with a targeted battlecry, click the minion and click the battlecry target (no need to click the battlefield).